# What is the difference between swiftkey and swiftkey x?

Tags: swiftkey

Using the Amazon Appstore I have "Swiftkey" and "Swiftkey X". When I install one there is an update for the other. It's getting confusing. What is the difference and which one should I install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The SwiftKey website](http://www.swiftkey.net/) no longer lists anything called "SwiftKey" only "SwiftKey X". I have to assume this means "SwiftKey" was an earlier product, possibly a beta?

Comment: Swiftkey wasn't a beta. Just that 'Swiftkey' was renamed to 'SwiftKey X' to indicate a brand new version.